# Expectation of the distance from the origin for a point on a disk of a unit circle

Tags: probability, expectation, circles

> A random point is chosen uniformly in the unit disk {$(x, y) : x^2 + y^2 \le 1$}. Let R be its
>   distance from the origin.
>
> (a) Find E(R) using 2D LOTUS.
>
> (b) Find the CDFs of $R^2$ and of R without using calculus, using the fact that for a Uniform distribution on a region, probability within that region is proportional to area. Then get the PDFs of $R^2$ and of R, and find E(R) in two more ways: using the definition of expectation, and using a 1D LOTUS by thinking of R as a function of $R^2$.

Please, help me to solve the problem.

I did the following so far:

$f(x,y)=\frac1{2r^2\pi}$,  when $x^2+y^2 \le1$, then $f(y)=\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac1{2r^2\pi}$dx=$\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\pi r^2}$;
$f(x|y)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

since R=$x^2+y^2$; $P(R \le r)=f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le r|Y=y)f(y)=f(-\sqrt{r^2-y^2} \le x \le \sqrt{r^2-y^2}|Y=y)f(y)$

What to do next? I want to find PDF to find $E[R]$

Withut calculus CDF of R will be $\frac {\pi r^2 }{\pi}=r^2 => f(R)=2r $

$E[R]$-?

Comment: The radius of the unit circle is one  and is not random, thus your title has little to do with the question. Your title should be something like "expectation value of distance from the origin for a point on a disk"

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks. Can you help me to find a PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a) with LOTUS, you do not try to find the pdf for R. Rather use the joint pdf, $f(x,y)={1\over\pi}$ for $x^2+y^2\le1$ and $0$ otherwise:
$$E[R]=\int\int\sqrt{x^2+y^2}f(x,y)\,dxdy$$
To do the integral, you can now transform to $(r,\theta)$, giving,
$$E[R]={1\over\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}r\,rdr\,d\theta=2\int_0^{1}r^2dr$$
The form is the same as for part (b), where
$$E[R]=\int_0^1rf(r)dr$$
using the pdf $f(r)$ that you found.

Hopefully you do the rest of the problem now...